# Cucumber JVM generates empty JSON report

Tags: cucumber-jvm

I have a suite of Cucumber tests being run by Jenkins periodically. Most runs are not generating a JSON report. More specifically, a zero sized JSON file is created. I'm using version 4.3.1 of cucumber-java, cucumber-java8 and cucumber-junit and Java 1.8.

My test setup is a little convoluted. Jenkins runs a job every 2 hours to run the tests. This job runs in its own Docker container (running a Linux image) wherein a fresh clone of the test repo is created. Jenkins then executes Gradle to build and run the tests.

In the Jenkins console output I can see Gradle starts the tests and presumably executes some but never completes them all. But there is no error or exception from Gradle, it simply stops running. Nor is there any message about the JVM exiting with a non-zero status.

There is the occasional run of the tests that will produce a non-empty JSON report. This tends to coincide with all of the tests passing, but not always.

Unfortunately I am not able to post the Jenkinsfile, build.gradle or anything else. If you need further details I might be able to provide small snippets.

Comment: What is the reason you are using both cucumber-java and cucumber-java8 in the same project? Afaik the json is generated once the tests are run, so there not being a report when the tests hang is expected behaviour to me. I'd be more interested in why your tests are hanging...

Comment: @Marit It's because the tests are using both annotated functions and lambda expressions for the test steps. From reading https://cucumber.io/docs/installation/java/ I gathered I'd need both of those dependencies. I don't believe the tests are hanging. The runs of the Jenkins job continue right on to the next bits of code in the Jenkinsfile and the total run time for the job is significantly less than when the tests run to completion.

Comment: Afaik you'd use one or the other (the docs, of which I am the main contributor) state "otherwise" between the two suggesting you'd use only one. I am not sure whether using both will lead to trouble, that's why I asked. Still, my question would be what happens when the tests do not, as you say, "run to completion". I assume that's why there is no report.

Comment: @Marit Naturally one of the devs on my team has broken the tests. It might be a bit before I can make sure including just one dependency works. Also, it now seems as though each run of the tests is writing out the JSON file. But I'm not sure if that's a result of the broken tests.

Comment: Well, at least you get a report now? If you'd like more help with Cucumber, please join us on one of the [support channels](https://cucumber.io/support) ;)